# Try Except Not Working With Email Function

Tags: python, oracle

Hello all I've got a piece of code that I'm using to send an email encase there is some kind of error when connecting to an Oracle database. The **Send_Email** function works perfectly fine outside of the Try Except statement but doesn't seem to work within the Try Except statement?

The reason behind this code was because the Oracle database went down today and my SQL query couldn't run. I just wanted to create a simple Try Except statement that works with my Send_Email function and i can send myself and email with the error within the body of the email. The error that originally came up was ORA-12514 cx_Oracle.DatabaseError. But regardless of the error I just want to be aware of what the exception is automatically via email.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

def Send_Email(to, cc='', bcc='', subject='', body='', attachment='' ):
    import win32com.client
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = to
    mail.CC = cc
    mail.BCC = bcc
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.body = body
    if attachment == '':
        pass
    else:
        mail.Attachments.Add(Source=attachment)
    mail.send


connection = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'password', 'hostname:port/SERVICENAME')

try:
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE", connection)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    Send_Email(to='myemail@email.com', subject='AUTO: Database Error', body=str(e))
except Exception as e:
    Send_Email(to='myemail@email.com', subject='AUTO: Other Error', body=str(e))
finally:
    print('Working')
```

Comment: "but doesn't seem to like working" - why does it not work? Do you get an error? Something else?

Comment: The database went down today which gave me an cx_Oracle.DatabaseError ORA-12514. Eitherway I just wanted my Python code to capture the error and send me an email within the body of my email, regardless of what error occurs.

Comment: That makes sense but you still haven't told us what the exact problem is.

Comment: the Send_Email function doesn't work within the try except part of the script but works outside of the try except statement. Does that help?

Comment: That's a step closer... What does 'Doesn't work' mean? It fails with an error? You don't receive the email? Something else?

Comment: So if I remove the try except statement and just run the Send_Email function it works fine. But as soon as I except and run the Send_Email function nothing happens.

Comment: How are you forcing the exception to occur? Are you sure the `Send_Email` method is actually being called?

Comment: I've just tested the code again and changed my SQL query to garbage and the code works and sent me an email Execution failed on 'SELECT msg FROM blablabla'. But for some reason when the database was down my code didn't send an email out notifying me there was an outage. Perhaps my exception is not capturing the Oracle error correctly?

Comment: I think @Ctznkane525 's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Put your database connection in the try like this.  When it cannot connect, it happens before the try section.

I want to note, a good way to retest this on your local machine would be to change your tnsnames (or whatever file you are using for configuration) to a setting that doesn't exist.  That way you can test an outage without changing the code.

```
try:
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'password', 'hostname:port/SERVICENAME')
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE", connection)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    Send_Email(to='myemail@email.com', subject='AUTO: Database Error', body=str(e))
except Exception as e:
    Send_Email(to='myemail@email.com', subject='AUTO: Other Error', body=str(e))
finally:
    print('Working')
```